# Getting 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable' error

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, loops

In the following custom function:

```
def get_a_random_memory(length, lower_sum_range, upper_sum_range):

    memory = list()


    for i in range(0, length):
        memory.append((2 * random.randint(0, 1) - 1))


    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, length):
        if len(memory) == 0:
            sum = memory[i]
        else:
            sum = sum + memory[i]
```

I am getting the following error.

```
>>> print memories.get_a_random_memory(10, 1, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\omarshehab\PycharmProjects\practice\memories.py", line 28, in get_a_random_memory
    if len(memory) == 0:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I assume I am accessing the list variable memory correctly.

Any help please?

Comment: I suspect you have a line starting with `len =` somewhere else in your code, which is overshadowing the built-in `len` function.

Comment: also (not related to your issue, but still) why would `len(memory)` ever be `0`? if it were, `length` would be `0`, and you wouldn't go into the loop anyway. Anyway, you could simply use `sum(memory)` instead`. But don't use `sum` as a variable name, as it is a built-in, and you are shadowing it.

Comment: I think you are accessing it correctly, I got no errors running this on my machine. Perhaps giving us more code will help?

Comment: @Kevin, there is only one instance of 'len' in my code.

Comment: If your interactive prompt has been running for a long time, you could have overshadowed `len` many hours ago and forgotten about it. Try starting a new interactive prompt and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: Tried it. it seems to be working fine. you seem to have some other conflicting variable.

Comment: @Kevin Cleaning the prompt worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider doing it as follows:

```
def get_a_random_memory(length, lower_sum_range, upper_sum_range):
    memory = [(2 * random.randint(0, 1) - 1) for i in xrange(length)]
    total = sum(memory)

    print memory
    print total

get_a_random_memory(10, 0, 0)
```

You should avoid using `sum` as a variable as there is already a Python function with that name that performs the calculation automatically on a list.

This script would for example display:

```
[1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
-2
```